# AG-GRID value formatter not working for dynamically generated currency

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to use a value-formatter in my AG-GRID table for displaying currency information.

This works perfectly when I have a hardcoded value in the formatter, in this case the unicode for 'Euros'

```
currencyFormatter(params) {
  return '\u20ac' + params.value;
}
```

However, I dont know in advance what currency I will need to format the data in, as it is dynamically generated. If I try an use a value that is available in my component (like below) it doesn't like it!

```
currencyFormatter(params) {
  return this.currencyUnicode + params.value;
}
```

There it throws in the console is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultCurrency' of undefined
```

It seems like all 'this' component variables are not available inside the currencyFormatter. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to access your component variables, you will have to bind your component context - **this**  to the `valueFormatter`

```
...
name : 'Currency',
field : 'currency',
valueFormatter: this.currencyFormatter.bind(this) //bind your component's context here
...

currencyFormatter(params) {
  return this.currencyUnicode + params.value;
}
```

This is a common javascript problem. Here is a good [read](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/)

Also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53241925/983929) describes the 2 ways you can reference `this`.